# Determining stiffness of spring by dynamic method

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

[image]I have been measuring stiffness of spring in physics lab by dynamic method. I made graph in MS Excel $\omega^2 =f (1/m)$ and than linear regression. I need to know, if in equation $y = kx + q$ the $k$ is stiffness and what is $q$ in this equation?

Comment: Well what is $y$ and what is $x$? $q$ is whatever $y$ is when $x=0$ right?

Comment: Show a picture of your plotted data, or provide the raw data.  This will allow others to take a guess regarding the meaning of "q".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $k$ is the stiffness constant. Since $\omega^2=\frac{k}{m}$ , and $y=\omega^2$, $x=1/m$.

For $x=1/m=0$, mathematically, $m$ should be infinity. But your experiment would probably only measure $m$ within some range. So, if you plot those points you can say that there exists a linear relationship. As to $q$, it should be approximately zero because $x=1/m=0$ means that $m$ is very large.